# Which cluster manager spark is using in this use case?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hadoop cluster with 4 nodes. And I create some hive tables from files stored in hdfs. Then I configure mysql as the hive metastore and copy the hive-site.xml file inside conf folder of spark.

To start the hadoop cluster I started the dfs and also the yarn.sh. Then I created the hive tables, and now Im executing some queries against hive tables from spark sql using hivecontext, like:

```
var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
query = hiveContext.sql("select * from customers");
query.show
```

My doubt is, in this case which cluster manager spark is using? Is the yarn? Because I started the yarn with `./start-yarn.sh` command? Or I need to configure something to be yarn and If i didnt it uses another cluster manager as deafult?
And in your opinion which cluster is better for this case? Or its indifferent?

Answer (score 2):

It uses your local, client or cluster based on your `--master` during spark-submit.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class myclass \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \ 
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  myapp.jar \
```

or you can specify in the code like below

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
             .setAppName("myapp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

If it is spark-shell,

```
spark-shell --master yarn
```

By default, I believe it uses local mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that cluster that you are saying local, is the spark stand alone cluster? Because in the documentation it just appears stand alone, yarn or mesos. And with your code to set yarn the cluster manager its showing an error in "val sc = new SparkContext(conf)", Im getting "28: error: not found: type SparkContext.

Comment: Did you import import org.apache.spark.SparkContext? or you are working on shell?

Comment: so, you can specify when you are launching. Editing in answer